# The converse of Tychonoff theorem

Tags: general-topology

For each $i\in I$, $(X_i,\mathcal T_i)$ is a compact topological space. $\mathcal T$ is any topology on
$$\prod_{i\in I}X_i$$
such that for each $j\in I$ the projection:
$$\pi_j:\prod_{i\in I}X_i\to X_j$$
is continuous.

If $\left(\prod_{i\in I}X_i,\mathcal T\right)$ is compact, is $\mathcal T$ the product topology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the $X_i$ are Hausdorff spaces, then yes, but without the Hausdorff assumption there are counterexamples.

Counterexample: Take a product of two 2-element sets $X_i$, each with the indiscrete topology.  The product topology is also indiscrete, but any other topology on the product set, for example the discrete topology, is also compact and makes the projections continuuous.

If the $X_i$ are Hausdorff spaces, then so is the product with the usual product topology.  Your $\mathcal T$ has to be at least as fine as the usual product topology in order to make the projections continuous. But the only way for a compact topology to be at least as fine as a Hausdorff topology on the same set is for them to be the same topology.